# Python: TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Label

def open_window():
    menu = Toplevel(root)
    menu.geometry("800x800")
    menu.title("my game's menu")
    menu.resizable(False, False)
    menu.geometry("800x800")
    lbl = Label(menu, text ="Hello!").pack

    menu.mainloop()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
Label = Label(root, text="Are you ready?")
Label.pack()


root.title("quick question")


btn = Button(root, text="Yes", command= open_window)
btn.pack(padx=20, pady = 20)
root.mainloop()
```

I got this error while I was working on previously seen code:  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\naujas zaidimas\scratch.py", line 11, in open_window
lbl = Label(menu, text ="Hello!").pack
TypeError: 'Label' object is not callable

Does anyone know why/how to fix it?

Comment: What do you think `Label` represents? You've defined a variable named `Label` and tkinter has a class named `Label`. How do you think python knows which one you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The code has a number of fairly obvious errors and one insidious error

This import plays no role in current code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Not a good or preferred way to import tkinter

This will cause problems later on

```
from tkinter import *
```

This is unnecessary with the current inport method

```
from tkinter import Label

def open_window():
```

The rule for Python functions is: Names created in functions stay in functions.

It will require a `global` instruction to make 'menu' available elsewhere in your code

```
menu = Toplevel(root)
menu.geometry("800x800")
menu.title("my game's menu")
menu.resizable(False, False)
```

Duplicated geometry instruction

```
menu.geometry("800x800")
```

This object has already been defined as a Label object so trying to name it throws a `TypeError`

```
lbl = Label(menu, text ="Hello!").pack()
```

This is unnecessary since `root.mainloop()` has already been executed

```
menu.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
```

Here is another naming problem caused by the import method chosen

```
Label = Label(root, text="Are you ready?")
Label.pack()
root.title("quick question")
```

This button will enable you to create MANY `Toplevel` windows

The problem is, ALL of them will be called 'menu'!?

This is the insidious error

```
btn = Button(root, text="Yes", command= open_window)
btn.pack(padx=20, pady = 20)
root.mainloop()
```

```py
# This solution avoids all the previous problems

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("quick question")
root.geometry("400x300")

tk.Label(root, text = "Are you ready?").pack()
# This will give tkinter time to process the given instructions.
root.update()

menu = tk.Toplevel(root)
# withdraw will make menu temporarily invisible
menu.withdraw()

menu.title("my game's menu")
menu.geometry("800x800")
menu.resizable(False, False)

tk.Label(menu, text = "Hello!").pack()
# command will now make menu window visible
btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Yes", command = menu.deiconify)
btn.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import *

def open_window():
    menu = Toplevel(root)
    menu.geometry("800x800")
    menu.title("my game's menu")
    menu.resizable(False, False)
    menu.geometry("800x800")

    lbl = Label(menu, text ="Hello!").pack()

    menu.mainloop()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
lbl1 = Label(root, text="Are you ready?").pack()



root.title("quick question")


btn = Button(root, text="Yes", command= open_window)
btn.pack(padx=20, pady = 20)
root.mainloop()
```

I Played around both our codes and now somewhy it works.

Comment: are you solving your problem?

Comment: "somewhy it works" is not a clear way to tell how your code works. it should be clearer if you're going to post this as an answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very useful. Please consider editing your answer to include a description of what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.